# How to plot a table with colors depending on the values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

let's assume that I have this dataframe `df` transfered from a matrix:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8

1   1399    17  4   3   0   0   0   0
2   11  374     2   3   1   4   0   1
3   7   0   187     4   0   0   1   1
4   2   3   4   308     0   0   0   3
5   2   0   0   0   280     3   0   1
6   0   2   0   0   2   81  0   3
7   1   0   2   0   2   0   154     4
8   0   0   1   2   1   1   8   552
```

I would like to plot this as a table in which the higher values are colored darker whereas the smaller values are colored lighter depending on their scalar value. But I am not sure if it is possible. All the plotting techniques seem to not include tables with colors. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: use a heatmap https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

Comment: @ilja exactly what I needed. Thanks. Didn't know it existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = df.to_numpy()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
         text = ax.text(j, i, a[i, j],
                        ha="center", va="center", color="w")

ax.set_title("Your title")
plt.imshow(a, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

For more details you may check [this URL](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.matshow(df, cmap=plt.cm.Greys)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What about the content of the grids? How do I make it print the values as well ?